# MySQL: Order by max date of a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-order-by

I have two tables - `groups` and `messages`.

---

Messages has the following fields `group_id` and `date_created`. So a lot of messages can be added to a single group. I want to select all groups from table - most relevant on top, i.e. order by latest message date. I've tried something like this

```
SELECT g.*, MAX(m.date_created) AS mdt FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN messages m ON g.id = m.group_id
ORDER BY mdt DESC;
```

But this query returns only one row and max message date from the whole table.

Comment: `cg` is not defined.  Your query should return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `group by`:

```
SELECT g.*, MAX(m.date_created) AS mdt
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     messages m
     ON g.id = m.group_id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY mdt DESC;
```